# "Induction" of periodic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

> [image]
>   [image]

How can "repeated applications" yield the result?

$f(a + bi) = f(a' + b'i + \underbrace{1 + \dots + 1}_{n} +( \underbrace{1 + \dots + 1}_{m})i ) = f(a' + b'i + (1 + i) + \underbrace{1 + \dots + 1}_{n -1 } +( \underbrace{1 + \dots + 1}_{m -1 })i ) $

So I think they mean to say that the last line implies,

$f(a' + b'i + \underbrace{1 + \dots + 1}_{n -1 } +( \underbrace{1 + \dots + 1}_{m -1 })i ) = … f(a' + b'i)$

But how can that be? Since $a' \neq a$ and $b' \neq b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just saying that if you start from $f(a'+b'i)$ and iterate $n$ times adding $1$ and $m$ times adding $i$ you get $f(a+bi) = f(a'+b'i)$:

$$
f(a'+b'i) = f(a'+b'i+1) = f(a'+b'i+2) = \dots = f(a'+b'i+n) = f(a'+b'i+n+i) = \dots = f(a'+b'i+n+mi) = f(a+bi)
$$